# Objective C - BOOL cast nil or NO

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, casting, boolean

Maybe dumb question:

```c
NSString *var = @"test";
if (var) {
```

Here `var` is casted to BOOL and compared to `YES`, isn't it ?

Is there any other value that can be transformed to `NO` when casted to `BOOL` than `nil` and `NO` ?

Comment: All C-like comparisons are promoted to `_Bool` (int), not `BOOL` (signed/unsigned char)

Comment: @CodaFi No, they aren't. Promotion to `int` occurs.

Answer (score 2):

> Here `var` is casted to `BOOL` and compared to `YES`, isn't it ?

No, it isn't, why would it?

> Is there any other value that can be transformed to NO when casted to BOOL than nil and NO ?

Any integral expression of value zero does the job.

Comment: For reference: if expressions were automatically evaluated to BOOL, then the slicing that signed char would do to the pointer would be a disaster.

Comment: @CodaFi Pretty much yes. `0xf00bar00`, and non-`NULL` suddenly becomes false thanks to alignment.

Comment: Just to stress a little bit more that `NO` is just a form of 0, it might be worth to recall how BOOL is defined: `typedef signed char     BOOL;` and `#define YES ((BOOL)1)` `#define NO ((BOOL)0)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 "No, it isn't, why would it ?" to know if the statement is valid for example. So can you tell me how the statement is validated ? Does it simply checks if the value in memory is not equal to `0` ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY No, it checks if the pointer is not `NULL`. If it is, it's false, if it isn't, it's true.

Comment: But `NO` is not `NULL` is it ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY It isn't, of course. But where do you see `NO` in `if (var)`?